# How to implement this UML class diagram in Java?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

[image]

I have this UML class diagram, but I don't know how to make the Java classes from it.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I think you should try something yourself first, maybe even start with UML class diagrams...

Comment: @deHaar , I've been trying it all day in VScode, but I haven't got the results yet

Comment: Do you know the meaning of the arrows and boxes in that diagram?

Comment: You need to be more specific what problem you're facing. If you know basics of UML class diagrams and Java you should be able to solve the task. If you don't understand some part of either the UML class diagram or how to make something specific in Java, ask precisely about that.

Comment: @deHaar ,@Amongalen, of course, each box has three parts, class name, attributes and methods, arrows represent the relationship between classes where the designated class stores the value of the designated class. but I have trouble writing it in java

Comment: Sorry, that's something you are obviously expected to do yourself. What have you tried so far and what makes you think that is wrong or incomplete? Do you know how to make Java classes in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the UML class diagram you can see there are two arrows going out from the Account class. Meaning of those two arrows are your SavingsAccount and CheckingAccount classes are inheriting from the Account parent class.So you must implement those two child classes with the aid of extends keyword in Java.
[Please refer this tutorial for a complete understanding](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_basic_notations.htm)

**Sample skeleton:**

```
public class Account{
//member variables and methods 

}
```

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account{
//member variables and methods

}
```

```
public class CheckingAccount extends Account {
//member variables and methods

}
```